# ios iTunesConnectで申請したいのですが、ビルドのアクティビティで「このビルドは無効です」と表示され先へ進めない

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

iosアプリの申請をしています。
xcode7.1からUpload to App Storeをしたのですが、iTunesConnect上でアップロードしたバイナリを確認すると「処理中」のままで20時間ほど経過しています。

ビルドのアクティビティを確認するとビルド番号の横に赤丸の中に「！」のマークで「このビルドは無効です。」と表示されています。

Upload時に「the resulting api analysis file is too large. we were unable to validate your api usage prior to delivery. this is just an informational message」とwarningは表示されましたがこれは問題ではないと思います。

対処法、ご存知の方いらしたらご教示願います。

Answer (score -1):

SocialConnectorか何かを使っていませんか？

こちらの記事を参考にしてみてください。
http://appneets.blog.jp/